# booting takes almost 4 minutes (pop os)

Tags: linux, boot, pop-os

i installed pop os 20.10 about two weeks ago , when the system is turned on , it takes about 4 minutes , also i check the ***systemd-analyze*** and ***systemd-analyze blame*** .
this is the result it gave me
[image: systemd-analyze]

[image: systemd-analyze blame]

my computer specification is 8 gb ram , core i5 processor , nvidia graphics card etc.

then why takes it long time to booting ,

how can i reduce booting time. ?
sorry for my poor English  .

Comment: Run `journalctl -b` and visually check where there's a pause. Post a dozen lines before it (while editing the question, **not** as a comment). Also, do **not** post screenshots of text, post text instead.

Comment: but there is shows a lot of lines , in that lines all will be in a one time .(dec 10 13:41:31) , there is not pause . .

Comment: Not generating service for XDG autostart app-org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power-autostart.service  .                                                           there is like this lot of results..

Comment: This is for Ubuntu, but is a starting point for things to review. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster You will not have snaps, which I think is a good thing as they are slow booting. Check UUIDs in fstab match all UUIDs in partitions.
`lsblk -f ` & 
`cat /etc/fstab`